# A program to tell me what filetypes are in this directory

Tags: file-types, recursion

I need a program which will recursively scan a directory and tell me all of the distinct filetypes that are inside the folder

Comment: Windows, MacOS or Linux? GUI or CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to look at a specific folder and it will sum up the file-types

And you can even create a report, which you could parse if you need it for something specific

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what OS you use but in BSD, Linux or other POSIX systems i'd use the file(1) command.

A simple `file dir/*` will do the trick.

Oh and to recursively scan a directory you can do this `find dir -type f -exec file {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Vista or 7 and you don't want to install a third party software solution, this can also be accomplished using PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32 | Select-Object Extension | Sort-Object -CaseSensitive Extension | Get-Unique -AsString
```